# Microsoft Entra External ID for customers - Assign default app role

Tags: microsoft-entra-id, microsoft-entra-external-id

Is there a way to automatically assign a default app role to users during the sign-up process using Microsoft Azure External ID? If so, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, currently there is no easy option to define it (including Entra portal). In the future I heard that this will be supported with Custom Authentication Extensions and event like *OnUserCreated* (or similar that will be provided by Microsoft). Here you can read more:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/concept-custom-extensions

In this case you could implement Azure Function to be triggered during the sign up process and with Microsoft Graph API you could assign specific app role to the user. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approleassignment?view=graph-rest-1.0) is the documentation on how to do it. Specifically you can look at [Grant an appRoleAssignment to a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint in Graph API.

However, as I mentioned, now there is no straightforward way to do it.

Comment: Is it possible to create a subscription specifically for the _customer tenant_ (which is different from my main tenant where the Azure Functions resides that is called by the Entra Events)? If so, we could deploy an Event Grid subscription and subscribe to [this event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/microsoft-entra-events#microsoftgraphuserupdated-event) I guess?

Comment: Well, I tried to add a subscription. but I was redirected to my main tenant to do it there. But then I could not add this new subscription to the customer tenant for deploying resources (eg EventGrid).

Then I guess there is this ugly workaround to get a self-build customer created event. Within the `OnAttributeCollectionSubmit` persist the `identities` data in the request body to be able to uniquely look up the user afterwards. In this step there is no user id yet. My assumptions is that the `...Submit` event is only called once in the user lifecycle....

Comment: ... Then in the `OnTokenIssuanceStart` event, you could query that identity whereever you have persisted it. If there is, it's a new user, assign a default role to the user id which is now available in the request body. Afterwards delete the temporarily persisted data. If there is no persisted data to begin with, it was an existing user logging in.

Comment: Hi @baouss, I apologize late reply, this was busy week!
Could you please provide more details what exactly you would like to achieve?
It is not possible to deploy Azure resources under customer MS Entra tenant. You have to do it under main Entra tenant which provides access to all subscriptions connected with it. If you want to subscribe to user change events, you should use Microsoft Graph API change notifications and use HTTP webhook.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-overview#supported-resources

Comment: Hi, I need to somehow subscribe to a "new user" event in the Entra ID customer tenant, since the custom auth extensions do not expose it. My idea was that with a subscription there, I can deploy Eventgrid notifications for Entra. But the webhook approach is also really viable. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-overview#code-samples:~:text=Changes%20to%20all%20users%3A%20/users) should be the relevant event. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Oh well, I'm just seeing that for the `user` resource it's stated that `Not supported for Azure AD B2C tenants.`. I hope this does not carry over to its successor Entra External Id.

Comment: Update: [it's not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78062497/unknown-precondition-failed-when-trying-to-create-ms-graph-subscription/78062624#78062624)

Comment: For Azure AD B2C Graph Notifications will not work definitely (as you mentioned). However, for MS Entra External ID it should. I have not tested it yet but I assume it will work as MS Entra ID uses the same technology underneath as standard MS Entra ID tenant.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this and reply. This is much appreciated. The post I linked was mine from earlier. I used your feedback to try to create such a subscription. It didn't work for entra external but did for regular Entra. Please feel free to review what I have done, I might have overseen something. Eg what comes to mind now, is that I might not have assigned sufficient permissions to the service principal. I will double check it also and report back

Comment: Reporting back! According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) `User.Read.All` is required in this case, `User.ReadWrite.All` are currently granted to the service principal, so permissions should be ok. Were you successful in creating a user subscription in the Entra External ID customer tenant?